# Loop Encountered When Using Flood Fill

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, flood-fill

I have encountered an infinite loop when running the following code.  Inside a grid that is surrounded by blocks, a predefined square is started with that this implementation runs off of.  A square is labeled as one if it needs to be visited and two if it has been visited.  I can't seem to find a solution and I would love a few helpful hints.

```
one_count=1;
while(one_count>0){
    for(int i=0;i<24;i++){
        for(int c=0;c<80;c++){
            if(create[i][c]=='1'){
                if(create[i-1][c]==' '){
                    create[i-1][c]='1';
                }
                if(create[i+1][c]==' '){
                    create[i+1][c]='1';
                }
                if(create[i][c-1]==' '){
                    create[i][c-1]='1';
                }
                if(create[i][c+1]==' '){
                    create[i][c+1]='1';
                }
                create[i][c]='2';
            }
        }
    }
    one_count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<24;i++){
        for(int c=0;c<80;c++){
            if(create[i][c]=='1'){
                one_count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like in your first iteration you are accessing create[-1].

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Clarification is needed, the point in which you start does not land on the rim and the fill should never check a point on the rim because it is not an empty space (' '), but an X ('X').

Comment: It's not clear to me how one_count can ever be 0 at the end of the loop. What are the initial conditions of the square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code on random data (with the edges being 'X'). I didn't encounter any loops.

Also there is no reason why you should run into problems. Every pixel is checked in every iteration and all '1's are guaranteed to be changed to '2's. There is no way back, not possible to loop.

Maybe you could supply more information about the behaviour of the program.

**BTW**:
There is a small quirk in your code. The flood fills very fast to the bottom and the right because you're writing your map already during the cycle (difficult to explain -> example)

- beginning of cycle: everything is ' ' except create[2][2]=='1'
- check all elements until create[2][2], write '1' into neighbours and '2' into self
- check next element i.e. create[2][3] which is also '1' and fill neighbours
- etc.

so after the first cycle you would expect only create[2][2]=='2' but everything to the right and down from it is also =='2'.

It doesn't break your code at the moment but it might lead to unexpected results if you change something.

Comment: Thank you for the observation! I will change the program accordingly. Also, this section of my program should be self contained and explaining the entirety of it might make a good lecture. =D This must mean something else in the larger scope of things is amiss, which is strange because if I delete this section of code it runs smoothly.  Again, thanks for your help!